# javascript capture onload & onunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying to capture window.open **onload** and **onunload** event.

the only problem i face when i put other domain URL.

for e.g:

When the URL is for the same page, both event trigger perfectly as i want it.

`window.open("/")`

[PLUNKER for same page URL](http://plnkr.co/edit/iWVmeUr0zIfdrzbHO4zL?p=preview)
....................When i try to put other domain or page URL, the onload & onunload event doesn't trigger

[PLUNKER for other page URL](http://plnkr.co/edit/jFayCsFyOop4erAGzqjG?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `window.open` method you should use this:

```
window.location.href='https://www.google.com.vn/';
```

As for [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) we have:

> Loads a resource into either a new browsing context (such as a window)
>   or one that already exists, depending on the specified parameters.

and for `window.location.href` property change it is different: it acts as a page redirect.